# Is there a function satisfying the following properties $ f^{n}(x)=(f(x))^{n+1}$??

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

Is there a function with the following properties?

$$ f(x)=f(x) $$
$$ f'(x)=f(x)^2 $$

$$f^{(n)}(x)=\left(f(x)\right)^{n+1}$$
where $f^{(n)}$ denotes the $n$th derivative, and by convention $f^{(0)}(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We can use the chain rule to show that there is only one such function:
$$ f'(x) = f(x)^2, $$
and differentiate both sides and use $f''=f^3$:
$$ f(x)^3 = f''(x) = 2f'(x)f(x) = 2f(x)^2f(x), $$
so $f(x)^3=2f(x)^3$, so $f(x) \equiv 0$.

Comment: Oh, and for anyone wondering about if you only have it for one $n>3$, keep differentiating and applying the chain rule and the relation $f'=f^2$.

Answer (score 5):

The function $x \mapsto 0: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is one such.

Comment: To downvoter: Please check the question again...

Comment: I don't get the downvotes. This is the first and most obvious example, and the question doesn't say find ALL such functions. +1

Comment: And +1 from me to neutralize the insidious down voter!